# redirect requests to the old endpoints to the new controllers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redirect, routes, controller

In my app the Frontend sends request to

```
resources :orders, only: [:index, :create]
```

but I built another route with a new controller, which is this one:

```
resources :new_orders, only: [:index, :create]
```

Is there a way to redirect all requests coming from `orders` to the new created controller of `new_orders`?

I tried something like this:

```
:orders, only: [:index, :create], to: redirect('/new_orders')
```

It uses the correct NewOrdersController and returns the json specified this controller. However the frontend can't find the orders.

Comment: What is it that you actually want to do here - create an actual redirect or to just have the routes go to the new controller? Why do you even think you need this?

Comment: I want the routes go to the new controller.
I need it, because the Frontend still uses the old route `orders`.
So the plan is the following:
1. Create the new route and new controller in the Backend. Frontend still uses the old route, but this route should point to the new controller.
2. The frontend is updated with the new routes.
3. The old route is deleted from the Backend.